# Bind multiple dropdowns from a single list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

In MVC, I have a `List<CityModel>` which contains CityID, City, StateID, State, CountryID, Country. By using  the below code I'm able to get the list of cites:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> objCityList;
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> objStateList;
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> objCountryList;
using (CityModel objCityModel = new CityModel())
{
  List<CityModel> cityList =  objCityModel.getCityList();
  objCityList = cityList.AsEnumerable().Select(m => new SelectListItem() {
                    Text = m.City,
                    Value = Convert.ToString(m.CityID)
                });
}
```

How can I bind distinct State and Country from `cityList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want to extract the State and Country lists from the City list. To do that, you can use something like this

```
objStateList = cityList.GroupBy(item => item.StateID, (key, items) => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = items.First().State,
    Value = Convert.ToString(key)
});
objCountryList = cityList.GroupBy(item => item.CountryID, (key, items) => new SelectListItem
{
    Text = items.First().Country,
    Value = Convert.ToString(key)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the one list, but change the which property is displayed in the combobox. The selected item is of the same type as the objects on the list.

In your view model just expose the `CityList` property and then bind the comboboxes `ItemsSource` to that property.

You can do all this in XAML for instance, like this:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}"
         DisplayMemberPath="City"
         SelectedItem={Binding SelectedCity, Mode=TwoWay>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}"
         DisplayMemberPath="County"
         SelectedItem={Binding SelectedCounty, Mode=TwoWay>
</ComboBox>

<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding CityList}"
         DisplayMemberPath="State"
         SelectedItem={Binding SelectedState, Mode=TwoWay>
</ComboBox>
```